# How to check if element exists after the current element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check the following

if after `$('.brandModelLineWrapper')` there isn't a `clearfix` div, add it:
`$('.brandModelLineWrapper').after("<div class='clear'></div>")`

How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.next()` with `:is` selector to check if it is div with class clear. and you can use `.after()` or `insertAfter()` to append the clear div based on first condition:

```
 if(!$('.brandModelLineWrapper').next().is('div.clear')){
     $('.brandModelLineWrapper').after("<div class='clear'></div>");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**next()**](http://api.jquery.com/next/) with a specific selector to check

```
if(!$('.brandModelLineWrapper').next('div.clear').length){
    $('.brandModelLineWrapper').after("<div class='clear'></div>");
}
```